# Error after cloning a remote symfony3 repository

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I have a remote repository that I tried to clone locally using

```
composer install
```

This worked fine for installing all the bundles and re-creating the `parameters.yml`, however I get an error right at the end which seems to be related to the change in directory structure from Symfony2->Symfony3:

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>
> Could not open input file: app/console
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

Clearing the cache we can do manually but is this the only issue or would there be anything else being terminated that we should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this was caused by a change in composer.json.

In sf2 there was a config section specifying the binary directory.

In sf3 this all appears in the "extra" section, mine looks like this:

`"extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
}`

Once I had set `symfony-bin-dir` to "bin" everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the path **app/console** has moved to **bin/console** in the third version of Symfony

Comment: Hi @rudak - yes I realise the Symfony3 directory structure differences is causing the problem but I'm wanting to know if there's any other steps from `composer install` that are steps that aren't processed because of this

Comment: Do you start your project from a clean Sf3 base or did you copy/paste files from older Sf2 project ? (check your composer.json ?)